# Collectors.toMap gives compilation error (String,List<String) is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, java-stream, type-inference

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student student = new Student();
        StudentDB studentDb = new StudentDB();

        System.out.println("All Elements from the List \n");
        studentDb.getStudentList().forEach(System.out::println);

        Map<String, List<String>> studentMap = studentDb.getStudentList().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(student.getName(), student.getActivities()));

    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want something like `Student::getName` and `Student::getActivities`. Method references, not immediate calls to the methods.

Comment: Map<String, List<String>> studentMap = studentDb.getStudentList().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getName(), s -> s.getActivities())); It is working fine. But if i use method reference, i get compile time error. Map<String, List<String>> studentMap = studentDb.getStudentList().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(student::getName(), student::getActivities()));

Comment: @mmathank careful, `student::getName` and `Student::getName` (capitalized *S*) are **not** the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thing, you're using `student.getName()`, which just calls a method on an object, so you'll get its name and its activites, you'll get values, no generic method to end the Stream

---

The [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) expects you to pass functions (`Function<Student,String>` for key, `Function<Student,List<String>>` for value), that from a `Student` will give something else

- You can express it with a lambda : `s -> s.getName()`

  ```
  Map<String, List<String>> studentMap = studentDb.getStudentList().stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getName(), s -> s.getActivities()));
  ```
- Or method reference `Student::getName`, you use the method itself, not applied on a specific object

  ```
  Map<String, List<String>> studentMap = studentDb.getStudentList().stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getName, Student::getActivities));
  ```

Comment: @mmathank Exact, you may not give a specific call to an object's method, but in general at the method itself, because it'll be applied to ALL object of the Stream

Answer (score 2):

The `toMap()` method expects a `Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper` and a `Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper` which map elements of your `Stream` to the keys and values of the `Map`:

```
Map<String, List<String>> studentMap = 
    studentDb.getStudentList()
             .stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getName, 
                                       Student::getActivities));
```

or

```
Map<String, List<String>> studentMap = 
    studentDb.getStudentList()
             .stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(student -> student.getName(), 
                                       student -> student.getActivities()));
```

Comment: @Lino The OP's `Student student = new Student();` seems to be part of the OP's mistake, so I'd just remove that. The name of the lambda expression argument is a matter to taste.